# How to compute the mean of weights of multiple models?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn, federated-learning

Hi i'm a student and i'm working on a Federated Learning problem, but before doing that with the proper tools like OpenFL or Flower, I started a little experiment to try in local to train using this technique.

I managed to train multiple models using IID data, now I'm struggling with the `local_update()` function that should collect the models and then i need to take all the weights of these models and compute their mean.
I read some documentation of Keras and Tensorflow that I'm using for my work, and i found some functions but i can't get it to work properly.

Currently this is my `local_update()` that's not working

```
    def local_update(self, models):

        
        weights = []
        #Take the weights of the models and compute the mean then return the weights to an updated model

        for model in models:
            for layer in model.layers:
                weights = layer.get_weights()
        
        #Compute the mean of weights  
        weights = np.mean(weights, axis=0)


        for layer in self.model.layers:
            self.model.set_weights(weights)     


        return self.model
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you get weights by each model layer but you always assign them to the same variable.

Hence at the end, you will have `weights` assigned to the average of the last layer weights.

[here](https://github.com/oscar-defelice/DeepLearning-lectures/blob/master/src/13.Federated_Learning.ipynb), you can find an example working and calculating the mean of weights.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i had a workflow a lot different from that of your, but it kinda worked.
Now i tryied 5 iteration of federated learning with my data and the final global model had 0 accuracy. 
I suspect that my validation set is wrong or something in my code is bugged.

Comment: unfortunately, currently the given link is broken

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have just updated the link